# Login and Register on the same Page nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Hi guys I am currently creating a website where the login and register is on the same page (for design reasons) I have also tried around but somehow I always get into an infinitely long loading loop.

Folder structure:

[image: 1]

The code I have currently divided as follows:

routes/auth.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const authController = require('../controllers/auth');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', authController.register);
router.post('/register', authController.login);

module.exports = router;
```

and controllers/auth.js:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE
});

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;
    let hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

db.query('SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?', [email], async(error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    if (results.length > 0) {
        return res.render('message/emailerror');
    } else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
        return res.render('message/pwderror');
    }

    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', { name: name, email: email, password: hashedPassword }, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            console.log('+++++++++++   User registered   ++++++++++')
            //return res.render('register', {
            //    message: 'User registered'
            //});
        }
    });

  });

 }

  //to login the user

   exports.login = async (req, res) => {
       try {
           const {emaillogin, passwordlogin} = req.body;
           if(!emaillogin || !passwordlogin) {
               return res.status(400).render('register', {
               message: 'Pls provide something'
            });
           }
         } catch (error) {
           console.log(error);
        }
       }
```

and the register.hbs where i have the html code:
Login Form:

```
        <div id="login">
        <h1 class="loginh1 transform2">Willkommen</h1>
        <form class="form transform3" action="/auth/register" method="POST">
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="email"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/mail.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="example@gmail.com" class="input" type="email" id="emaillogin" name="emaillogin">
            </div><br>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="password"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/lock.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Passwort" class="input" type="password" id="passwordlogin" name="passwordlogin">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="hidden" name="formType" value="signin">
            </div>
        </form>
        <button type="submit" class="bnlogin transform4">LOGIN</button>
    </div>
```

Register Form:

```
        <div class="registerarea transform7">
        <h1 class="registerh1 ">Join us</h1>
        <form class="formregister" action="/auth/register" method="POST">
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="name"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/user.svg" height="30px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:30px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Your Name" class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="email"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/mail.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="example@gmail.com" class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="password"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/lock.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Passwort" class="input" type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="passwordConfirm"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/lock.svg" height="25px">
                    <span style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Passwort Bestätigen" class="input" type="password" id="passwordConfirm"
                    name="passwordConfirm">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="hidden" name="formType" value="signup">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btnregister">Lets go</button>
        </form>
```

So, I hope that someone of you can help me. That would be really great. Thanks in advance and best regards :D

Comment: "somehow I always get into an infinitely long loading loop" — When you do what, precisely?

Comment: after i click the submit button

Comment: Which submit button?

Comment: From signup form

Comment: can you provide the error you facing, like browser console.log?

Comment: And what have you done to debug it? Put some logging into your endpoint handlers. See which function(s) get entered. See which branches of `if`/`else` statements get called. Check what values the data you get from the body has.

Comment: So i have tried it again. No the register form works but the login form does not work. (I cannot select the input field for login email and login password

Comment: If the code ever gets inside `db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?'` then it has an `if` and an `else` and **neither** of them send a response to the browser.

Comment: yea at the moment it does not send any response to the browser

Comment: at db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?'